# Лагейда/легейда. Звідки пішло слово?

Tags: етимологія

Звідки до нас прийшло слово "лагейда"/"легейда"?

Його значення легко вишукується в [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/leghejda) або в [словнику з творів Івана Франка](https://slovnyk.me/dict/vts/%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B0)

> легейда — Леге́йда: — вайло, телепень [19] — недотепа [VI,VII]

Але його етимології не можу знайти ані в наших словниках, ані в словниках їдишу...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> <sub>Етимологічний словник української мови Інституту мовознавства ім. О. О. Потебні НАН України.</sub>
>
> [ЛЕҐЕ́ЙДА](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%BB%D0%B5%D2%91%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B0) «недотепа; ледар, лежень; незграбна людина, вайло»
>
> - запозичення з польської мови;
> - [польська] [*legiejda*] «ледар; незграбна людина; нездара, недотепа, волоцюга», [*legejda*, *łegejda*, *łygiejda*] «[те саме]» вважається нерегулярним жартівливим утворенням від *legać* «лягати», спорідненим з [українська] ляга́ти;

В пошуках натрапяв також на:

- Різні варіяцїї записа в книзї [*Етімолоґічний словник українських прізвищ — прізвищезнавство*](//books.google.com.ua/books?id=3iEfAAAAMAAJ&q=%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B0) (Василь Ірклієвський): *Легейда* → *Лагойда* → *Логойда* → …
- Різні тлуми в книзї [*Прізвища закарпатських українцїв: Історико-етимологічний словник*](//ia803002.us.archive.org/32/items/pryzv2005/pryzv2005.pdf#page=394) ([Павло Чучка](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D1%83%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)): укр. діал. ос. назви *лоґо́йда* — *бродяга, волоціога, пройдисвіт, шибеник, опришок* (Чопей 171). Пор. ще гуц. *лаґа́йда* — *ледар* (Гг 108).